# How to change output format of for-loop to string instead of a list?

Tags: mysql, node.js, for-loop

There's a for loop function in my code which looks like below.  I tried to use the output in a "select where in list" statement in MYSQL, but I have tried many ways to format the output differently so MYSQL statement will work.

```
let fish = [ {name: "flounder", color: "white"},
             {name: "salmon", color: "orange"},
             {name: "pike", color: "blue"} ];

// Initalize for loop to run for the total length of an array
for (let i = 0; i < fish.name.length; i++) {
    // Print each item to the console
    console.log(fish[i].name);
}
```

Actual output from the for loop

```
flounder
salmon
pike

or after I updated it an array it becomes
['flounder']
['salmon']
['pike']
```

Desired output would be like the following:

```
flounder, salmon, pike

and if i convert it to an array it should look like this

[flounder, salmon, pike]
```

I will need the specific format so my below SQL statement will work.

**select * from fish_list where name in (?)**

How can i convert the format to desired output? Thank you so much in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way can be

```
let fish = [ {name: "flounder", color: "white"},
             {name: "salmon", color: "orange"},
             {name: "pike", color: "blue"} ];

const nameArrRes = fish.reduce((nameArr,item)=>{
    return nameArr.concat(item.name);
},[])

console.log(...nameArrRes);
```

This will output :flounder salmon pike

Not sure what you mean by Array but if that needs to be the string you can always prep the string before feeding to SQL in case of array

Comment: Spent a few hours on this, was using for loop and couldnt make it work. Your code did the trick, thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

The first one: Make a string variable outside of the loop which you keep adding the value to + the comma. Then when you are done with the loop, print the variable.
The second one would be:
Make an array where you say; For each object in Fish, add that object to array at position [i]. This variable again has to be outside of the loop.
Reasoning:
Everytime the loop runs, the variable you create inside of the loop gets destroyed and remade. So whatever it contained before is deleted. Thats why you make the variable outside of the loop, so it persists and you can then have an array with the values you want, or a string with the print you want :)